# Chrome browser tab shares, how can I find who is it shared with?

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser-tabs

I am using Chrome browser on Windows 11

I am worried about my computer security and don't want to underestimate any issue.

I have been seeing this sign which says "This tab content is being shared"

[image]

I googled this and I found this means there is another device sharing the same media

such as in sharing a video from youtube to my TV

but in my case, Facebook is not open on any other device (I have FB on my phone but it is closed)

I am worried if that means someone is spying

Is there a way I can see who the content is shared with and more info about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the reason why this is happening

i am using the Volume Master extension

which can increase volume to more than 100%

and when i do so I get that sign of sharing

it is not actually sharing though